# How does Unix read a path name with two consecutive slashes? (e.g. /home/user//mystuff)

Tags: perl, unix, scripting, filesystems

Here's the reason why I'm asking this question: I write a lot of bash and Perl scripts, and I find myself having to concatenate two paths every so often. Something like this is typical:

```
my $prefix = "/home/user/";
my $suffix = "/mystuff";
...
chdir $prefix.$suffix;
```

The problem is that I don't always remember if I put a slash at the end of the prefix, or if I put a slash at the beginning of the suffix. So I could accidentally concatenate two slashes together, like in the above example.

So my main question is whether or not two consecutive slashes will cause any problems and why. But also, do programmers have a convention for this? In the code that other people write, do directory names always end with a slash? It would be nice if there is some consistent rule that I could follow.

Comment: Suggest you consider using a module such as `File::Spec` or similar, which handle all the separators for you, specific to the platform the script is running on, thereby improving portability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. Repeated slashes are treated as one by Unix systems, so always add one.

```
my $prefix = "/home/user";  # Or "/home/user/"
my $suffix = "mystuff";
my $dir = "$prefix/$suffix";
```

But if you want a canonised path for whatever reason (e.g. it's going to be displayed to a user), you can use:

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );
my $prefix = dir("/home/user");  # Or "/home/user/"
my $dir = $prefix->subdir($suffix);
say $dir;
```

Whether you start with `/home/user`, `/home/user/` or even `///home///user///`, you end up with:

```
/home/user/mystuff
```

Comment: That would be more efficiently written as `dir($prefix, $suffix)`.

Comment: @cjm, That would mean your code would have a mixture of Path::Class objects and plain paths. My code wouldn't have that. The `dir($prefix)` would be done long before `$suffix` comes into play.

Comment: @cjm, I also doubt that efficiency savings would be worth mentioning.

Comment: I don't really see how passing the plain paths to two separate functions is any more of a mixture than passing them both to one function.  I agree the run-time performance is not significant, but it's also less typing.

Comment: @cjm, Fine, I'll make the example more realistic even though that makes it less readable.

Answer (score 5):

Unix shells and kernels happily handle this, as well as things like "/firstpart/./secondpart", but generally you don't make trailing slash a part of the variable value to make path concatenation expressions look nicer: *${firstpart}/${secondpart}* rather than *${firstpart}${secondpart}*.

In scripts on Linux the *[readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink)* command line tool can be used to normalize file names.